# UIButton is disabled - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development

I'm new to swift programming and I'm trying to disable the save button until all other required buttons are selected, but when I try to do that with the button.isEnabled = false, it doesn't change even when all the buttons are selected. here is a sample code:

```swift
func disableButton () {
    if firstButton.isSelected && rightButton.isSelected  {
        saveButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        saveButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

when I remove the last line the save button works but when I put it back it's disabled even when the two other buttons are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have used `Storyboard` you have to link the 2 buttons into `@IBActions` , and within those `@IBAction` methods manipulate the `isSelected` property. Refer the example below.

**NOTE - Read the comments**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // 2 buttons that we will set the isSelected property
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

    // Button to disable/enable
    @IBOutlet weak var finalButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        finalButton.isEnabled = false // setting the button as disabled
    }

    /// This is the function triggered when you click on the "button1"
    @IBAction func didPressButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Here we will set the isSelected property of "sender" parameter, which is the button that calls this function. That is button 1
        sender.isSelected = sender.isSelected ? false : true
        //calling this function to make any updates to the UI if needed
        disableButton()
    }

    /// This is the function triggered when you click on the "button2"
    @IBAction func didPressButton2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Here we will set the isSelected property of "sender" parameter, which is the button that calls this function. That is button2
        sender.isSelected = sender.isSelected ? false : true
        //calling this function to make any updates to the UI if needed
        disableButton()
    }

    func disableButton () {
        if button1.isSelected && button2.isSelected  {
            finalButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            finalButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

What happens here is you will set the `isSelected` property of the button that calls the function in the function itself, and run the `disableButton()` function every time it is invoked for UI updates.
The final result will be,

[image]